# Como fazer para copiar o valor do textbox expecifico do UserFom aberto?

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6

Tem um jeito mais fácil que escrever
`x = UserForm1.textbox2.value`  ?

Essa instrução significa: **Copie o valor da caixa de texto1 do UserForm1**.

Eu queria substituir a declaração "UserForm1" por algo que signifique "UserForm aberto".

ou seja: copiar o valor da caixa de texto 1 do "UserForm aberto".

Comment: Caso seja em vb6 procure expor uma `Property Get` para consumir o valor do seu controle essa seria uma forma mais elegante. Outro ponto crie instancias dos formulários isso reduzirá o número de de falhas em sua aplicação, pois acessando diretamente o formulário não será descarregado.

Comment: Se você omitir o Userform o VBA já vai utilizar o Formulário Ativo, portanto com `textbox2.value` ele já realiza no texbox2 do userform. Já se quiser no textbox ativo você pode utilizar os módulos de Classe

Answer (score 0):

Pra pegar qualquer coisa de uma form que está aberta no momento, basta usar o "me":

```
a = me.textBox.value
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    For i = 0 To Forms.Count - 1
    If Forms(i).ZOrder = 0 Then
        Forms(i).TextBox1.text
    End If
    Next
```

Será que te ajuda?